# Select from one table on truthful IF condition, select from another on FALSE?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Here's what I've currently got:

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN chat.user_type = 's'
  THEN (SELECT name FROM students WHERE students . id = chat . user_id) AS name
  ELSE (SELECT name FROM teachers WHERE teachers . id = chat . user_id) AS name
FROM chat WHERE classroom_id = '2' ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

But it isn't working for me. I'm not sure how I would write this, so that it can select the name from one of two tables.

Comment: @DanielA.White Would you mind explaining how? A good explanation would really help me wrap my head around joins once and for all. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT *, CASE WHEN chat.user_type = 's'
               THEN students.name
               ELSE teachers.name 
          END AS name
FROM chat 
LEFT JOIN students ON students.id = chat.user_id
LEFT JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = chat.user_id
WHERE classroom_id = '2' 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

or

```
SELECT *, coalesce(students.name, teachers.name) AS name
FROM chat 
LEFT JOIN students ON students.id = chat.user_id AND chat.user_type = 's'
LEFT JOIN teachers ON teachers.id = chat.user_id AND chat.user_type = 't'
WHERE classroom_id = '2' 
ORDER BY timestamp ASC
```

Also see [this great explanation of joins](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)